# Preventing to submit too many forms on angular

Tags: angular, mean-stack

I begin to learn angular, and I am practicing angular. For this purpose, I created an app that related to forms. I can create a form and save it, then I can display it. 
 My problem is right now, I am trying to prevent, for example, submitting more than 20 forms. After 20 forms, I want to display an error message. 
For this purpose, I created a couple of functions, but they do not work good enough in the HTML. My code is below.

**post-create.component.ts**

```
export class PostCreateComponent {
   private postCounter = 0;

   @Output() postCreated = new EventEmitter<Post>();

   onAddPost(form: NgForm) {
      if (form.invalid) {
         return;
      }

      const post: Post = {
        title: form.value.title,
        content: form.value.content
      };

      this.postCreated.emit(post);
   }

   onAddPostCount() {
      this.postCounter++;
      console.log(this.postCounter);
   }

   onGetPostCount() {
     return this.postCounter;
   }
}
```

**post-create.component.html**

```
<mat-card>

   <form *ngIf="onGetPostCount() < 20" (submit)="onAddPost(postForm)" #postForm="ngForm" (submit)="onAddPostCount()">
      <mat-form-field>
         <input
           matInput
           type="text"
           name="title"
           ngModel
           required>
      <mat-error *ngIf="postForm.form.get('title')?.invalid">Please enter a title!</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <textarea
           matInput
           rows="4"
           name="content"
           ngModel
           required
           #content="ngModel">
        </textarea>
        <mat-error *ngIf="content.invalid">Please enter a content!</mat-error> 
      </mat-form-field>
      <button
         class="button"
         mat-raised-button
         color="primary"
         type="submit">Save Post
      </button>
      <mat-error *ngIf="onGetPostCount() > 20"> Count over 2</mat-error>
   </form>
</mat-card>
```

I was wondering how can I prevent to submitting, for example, more than 20 posts? How can I fix my code or Is there a way that makes is quicker and better?

[Live](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptuawn?file=src%2Findex.html)

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz

Comment: yes, i can @PrashantPimpale, but it does not show the angular material

Comment: Check my updated answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

- Use only one function to submit the form and add the
  `onAddPostCount()` function inside submit call function.
- Use the logic of allowing and disallow in TS file with one instead of
  repeating condition more than 2-3 times

HTML Code:

```
<mat-card>
    <form (submit)="onAddPost(postForm)" #postForm="ngForm">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput type="text" name="title" ngModel required>
      <mat-error *ngIf="postForm.form.get('title')?.invalid">
        Please enter a title!
      </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <textarea matInput rows="4" name="content" ngModel required #content="ngModel">
        </textarea>
        <mat-error *ngIf="content.invalid">
          Please enter a content!
        </mat-error> 
      </mat-form-field>
      <br>
      <button [disabled]="!isAllowToSubmit" class="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">
        Save Post
      </button>
      &nbsp;
      <button [disabled]="isAllowToSubmit" class="button" mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="resetPostCounter()">Reset
      </button>
      <mat-error *ngIf="!isAllowToSubmit"> 
        Count over 2
      </mat-error>
   </form>
</mat-card>
```

TS code:

```
private postCounter = 0;
private maximumNoOfPosts = 20;

isAllowToSubmit: boolean = true;

@Output() postCreated = new EventEmitter<any>();

onAddPost(form: NgForm) {
  if (form.invalid) {
     return;
  }
  const post: any = {
    title: form.value.title,
    content: form.value.content
  };

  this.postCreated.emit(post);
  this.onAddPostCount();
}

onAddPostCount() {
    if (this.postCounter == this.maximumNoOfPosts) {
      this.isAllowToSubmit = false;
    }
    else {
      this.postCounter++;
    }
}

resetPostCounter(){
    this.postCounter = 0;
    this.isAllowToSubmit = true;
}
```

[`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6o79q)